# What notation should I use to denote the sum of multiples of k smaller than n

Tags: summation, notation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want the clearest, simplest way to denote, for example, the sum of every multiple of 3 smaller than 62 which i could denote like: $$ \sum_{i=0}^{20}3i =0+3+6+…+60 $$ which was the way I found to write it, but when using variables it requires me to introduce the floor function:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right \rfloor}ki $$
So I wanted to know what would be a better way to write it without requiring the floor function

Comment: If you don't like using the floor function you could write $$\sum_{0\le i \le n/k} k\ i$$

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than using the floor function. More importantly, your maths doesn't line up with your English: if $n$ is a multiple of $k$, then your formula gives you the sum of multiples of $k$ *no greater* than $n$, not *smaller* than $n$.

Comment: @jjagmath: that's a good possibility. However, if you do it that way with $\LaTeX$ rather than here with MathJax, the $ki$ will be spaced much further right and it doesn't look very good.

Comment: @RobArthan That's more a problem of typography, which doesn't seems related with the OP question. As far as we know, it could be that the OP want to write it by hand in paper or a blackboard, or in MathJax, or in LaTeX, etc.

Comment: As someone whose research involves such sums all the time (and whose readers are used to this way of writing things), I use $\sum\limits_{\substack{0\le m\le n \\ k\mid m}} m$. Of course evaluating the expression requires converting to one of the other forms—but the notation itself is useful and worth considering.

Comment: @jjagmath: sure, it was just an observation. In any case, a bit of tinkering with $\LaTeX$ will let you move the $ki$ left.